# Sum of covariances equals variance of sum OR: how to estimate the relative importance of a time series for a sum of time series?

Tags: time-series, variance, covariance

I have n time series $x_1,\dots, x_n$ and the sum of these time series $x_{sum} = x_1 + \dots + x_n$.

I observed that the sum of all covariances between each time series and their sum equals the variance of that sum:

$cov(x_1,x_{sum}) + \dots + cov(x_n,x_{sum}) = var(x_{sum})$

Can I use this relationship to determine the relative importance of the individual time series for the sum of all time series?

e.g.: if I divide all covariances by the variance of the sum -- does that give me a percentage of "how important" one time series is for the sum of all time series?

Is this a known approach, and if yes, how is it called?

I searched for hours in order to find such a metric and it's beginning to drive me crazy.